# Is a club call sign with a suffix (i.e. /GOTA) permissible for a Field Day GOTA station?

Tags: united-states, field-day

The [2017 Field Day GOTA Station FAQ](http://www.arrl.org/files/file/Field-Day/2017/12-2017%20FD%20GOTA%20FAQ.pdf) states "The GOTA station uses a callsign different from the call used by the group’s main Field Day operation. The GOTA station must use the same, single callsign for the duration of Field Day." Would that mean that appending a suffix, e.g. /GOTA, to my club call sign is sufficient, or should I use my own personal call sign (since I'm in charge of my club's Field Day operation this year)?

ETA: This is for a Field Day operation based in the USA.

Comment: For questions about regulations you should say what country or region you mean. We might assume the FCC/US based on your call, but we should be sure to say this in the question as well as tag it with the region.

Comment: ...perhaps ability to actually read the post would;d be helpful

Comment: If that comment was directed at me, tagging with the region makes it helpful for others to find the Q&A. It is literally how this site works.

Comment: John - are your this site owner ?

Comment: Anyway, the main reason for regional clarification is because a fair number of non-ARRL/FCC countries participate in field day but they have different rules about call sign suffixes, So the answer might be different depending on where you are operating.

Comment: I believe appending a suffix is not in the spirit of the Field Day rules, so no.  Also, FCC says the suffix is suppose to start with a valid prefix for the country call signs, so /GOTA would not be legal either.

Comment: @JohnVE3WNA I've updated the post to reflect that this will be a US-based Field Day operation.

Answer (score 6):

For the ARRL Field Day, the rules state:

> 4.1.1.1. This station must use a different callsign from the primary Field Day station. The GOTA station must use the same callsign for the
> duration of the event regardless if operators change. The GOTA station
> uses the same exchange as its parent.
> http://www.arrl.org/field-day-rules

Since this states that a different callsign must be used, and does not specify that an identifier would suffice, it must be a different call sign.

It should be noted that you'll have to keep a log of the station operators and each of their contacts.

> 4.1.1.2. The GOTA station may be operated by any person licensed since the previous year’s Field Day, regardless of license class. It may
> also be operated by a generally inactive licensee. Non-licensed
> persons may participate under the direct supervision of an appropriate
> control operator. A list of operators and participants must be
> included on the required summary sheet to ARRL HQ.

Comment: @webmarc Good catch. I corrected my response.

Comment: cool, and thanks! deleted my comment since it's no longer relevant